# Status of a Python class defined within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
def myfn():
    class MyClass:
        pass


    return MyClass()


a = myfn()
b = myfn()

print(type(a) is type(b))
```

Here we can see that `type(a)` **is not** `type(b)`. Is this always guaranteed to be the case? Why doesn't the interpreter optimise this since the definition of `MyClass` doesn't depend on any parameters passed to `myfn`?

Comment: An "optimization" that changes behavior it's not allowed to change is a bug, not an optimization.

Comment: @user2357112 - that depends on the defined behaviour!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `class` statement, when executed **always** creates a new class object. Classes are not singletons. By putting the `class` statement in a function just lets you execute it more than once.

Class statements at the module level are executed just once because *modules are executed just once*, on first import.

You could bypass this by deleting the module object from the `sys.modules` structure; you'll note that the `Foo` class imported the third time is a different object after we removed the module:

```
>>> with open('demomodule.py', 'w') as demomodule:
...     demomodule.write('class Foo: pass\n')
...
16
>>> import sys
>>> from demomodule import Foo  # first import
>>> id(Foo)
140579578254536
>>> import demomodule  # just another reference, module is not run again
>>> id(demomodule.Foo)
140579578254536
>>> del sys.modules['demomodule']  # removing the module object
>>> import demomodule              # this causes it to be imported again
>>> id(demomodule.Foo)
140579574812488
```

The same can happen when you run a module as script then import the same module with `import`; scripts are run as the `__main__` module, using `import` to import the script *again* then also creates a separate module object for the imported name:

```sh
$ echo 'class Foo: pass
> import demomodule
> print(__name__, id(Foo), id(demomodule.Foo))
> ' > demomodule.py
$ python demomodule.py
demomodule 140718182184264 140718182184264
__main__ 140718182074440 140718182184264
```

Python is highly dynamic in nature; applying optimisations such as caching a class object produced by a function are fraught with problems. Your function might not take any parameters, but it is not operating in a vacuum. For example, I could replace the `__build_class__` hook function and insert an extra class into the bases of *any class created anywhere in Python*:

```
>>> def foo_class():
...     class Foo: pass
...     return Foo
...
>>> foo_class().__mro__
(<class '__main__.foo_class.<locals>.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> import builtins
>>> class Bar: pass
>>> orig_buildclass = builtins.__build_class__
>>> def my_buildclass(f, name, *bases, **kwargs):
...     return orig_buildclass(f, name, *((Bar,) + bases), **kwargs)
...
>>> builtins.__build_class__ = my_buildclass
>>> foo_class().__mro__
(<class '__main__.foo_class.<locals>.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Python is full of hooks like these.